# git File not found in any active repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, github-for-windows

Microsoft git provider in Visual Studio keeps spamming my output window with:

**"File not found in any active repository"**

I'm sure the file isn't ignored because I can see the changes on Github, the file changes are recorded and the file **is in repository**

How do I go about fixing this?

edit: it also gives wrong path in output window (which is outside of repository), by looking at "properties window" the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My file(s) somehow ended up in "Untracked Files", even when adding them new or coping and pasting other files.

My solution was to simply right-click on the untracked files > add

Team Explorer > Changes > Untracked Files > Add